# Как вычислить stroke-width в SVG

Tags: вёрстка, svg

Подскажите, как вычисляется толщина линии в SVG? Пример, мне нужно нарисовать квадрат 100х100 с толщиной линии 2 пиксела. При этом я рисую в координатах `viewBox="0 0 10 10"` Что нужно указать в  `stroke-width`? Значение `viewBox` я менять не могу.

```html
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="100">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

И обратные пропорции. Квадрат 20х20 viewBox="0 0 100 100" нужны те же 2 пиксела

```html
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="20">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: viewBox="0 0 10 10"-размер сцены для svg, квадрат 100 на 100 в нее не влезет

Comment: @Summersby но влазит же. Смотри код. Да, я рисую его как 10х10, но на экране он выглядит как 100х100. Вот мне нужно чтобы и стороны у него на экране были указанной толщины

Comment: так вы растягиваете там в теге svg до ширины 100px. Для квадрата 20х20 нужно в теге rect прописать ширину 20, высоту 20, а там в примере вы всей свг задаете ширину 20, а самому квадрату 100

Comment: @Summersby мне нужно сделать именно так, как я написал. Размер сцены я менять не могу, но мне нужно, чтобы при масштабировании svg на указанный размер, я получил строго определенную толщину линии

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код автора вопроса:

```html
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 10"
width="100" style="border:2px solid;">
        <rect id="rect" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"/> 
       <polyline  points="1,5 9,5" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" /> 
    </svg>
<script>
console.log(rect.getBBox()) 
</script>
```

Чёрная рамка, - это границы видимой части холста SVG 100x100px. Это так называемый `viewPort`, который определяется `width="100"` `height="100"` в шапке SVG файла.
Эта та область, которую видит пользователь на дисплее после рендеринга фигур svg

viewBox="0 0 10 10" виртуальная область, которая захватывается для вычислений рендеринга и её не видит пользователь.

После вычислений viewport / viewBox = 10
Другими словами один пиксель физической фигуры SVG растягивается на 10 пикселей viewPort.

Поэтому фигура, которая имеет физические размеры `10x10px` после рендеринга становится в 10 раз больше   `100x100px`. Соответственно линии становятся в 10 раз толще.

**Но есть ещё один нюанс.**
Так как границы прямоугольника идут по краю холста SVG, то они уменьшаются в два раза, так как половина слева от осевой, вторая половина справа от осевой.

Обратите внимание, я добавил зелёную линию по центру `stroke-width="2"` и она в два раза толще границ красного прямоугольника.

Поэтому необходимо изменить толщину границ прямоугольника на `stroke-width="4"`, тогда видимая, физическая ширина линии будет `2px`

Чтобы при любом значении viewPort `width`и `height` линия оставалась после рендеринга строго `2px` необходимо добавить , как советует **@Leonid** в своем ответе - `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`

### Решение:

1. stroke-width x 2 то есть, устанавливать в два раза толще, чтобы половина была равна, требуемому размеру
2. vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" - для того чтобы линия не меняла свою толщину при изменении масштаба (соотношение viewPort / viewBox) или при изменении только `width`

Ниже пример с 4 разными размерами квадратов, у которых толщина границы остается постоянной -`2px`

```html
 <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="20" >
        <rect id="rect" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="4"
            vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/> 
 </svg>
 <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="40" >
        <rect id="rect" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="4"
            vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/> 
 </svg>
 <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="100" >
        <rect id="rect" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="4"
            vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/> 
 </svg>  
  <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="200" >
        <rect id="rect" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="4"
            vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/> 
 </svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо за `vector-effect`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov главное в ответе это половина строки, ну а vector-effect первым предложил `@Leonid` хотя это общеизвестно

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, спасибо за отрубание линий на границах, вот в чем оказывается секрет!!! Я и не догадался глянуть даже, это мощно.

Comment: @Leonid И тебе благодарность. Надеюсь, что ты не в обиде. Вчера повстречал интересный вопрос-ответ по canvas, собираюсь  перевести. Думаю надо прокачать раздел canvas/

Comment: Я Антона не понял только. А в обиде могу быть только на себя, что не догадался почему вполовину тоньше линия))) Canvas, действительно, мертвая тема. Надо прокачать))

Answer (score 1):

x="10" y="10" - смещение квадрата относительно сцены

```html
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100">
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="20" height="20" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Мне нужен квадрат **на всю** сцену. У меня на рисунке не только один квадрат, а и еще объекты есть. И вопрос - как правильно рассчитать толщину линий у этих объектов\

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox - по-моему очевидно же, что тогда стороны квадрата должны быть равны значениям сцены.

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`, а толщину задать в CSS.

```css
rect {
    stroke-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="100">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="none" stroke="red" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
</svg>
```

Или можно задать толщину в относительных единицах SVG, но не знаю насколько они адекватно отражают именно пиксели CSS.

```html
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="400">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
</svg>
```

Для сравнения добавил толщину линии по-разному. Получается, что никакой разницы. В конце добавил пару `<div>` - сразу видно, что толщина в 2 пикселя там работает по-другому. Но считаю, что корневая задача, а именно выравнивание толщины элементов вне зависимости от масштабирования таким образом решается. А во-вторых, можно подогнать толщину линий под нужный окончательный эффект.

```css
.non-scale {
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid 2px red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="100">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
</svg>

<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="20">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
</svg>
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="100">
    <style>
        rect {
            stroke-width: 2px;
        }
    </style>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="none" stroke="red" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
</svg>

<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="20">
    <style>
        rect {
            stroke-width: 2px;
        }
    </style>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
</svg>
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="100" class="non-scale">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="none" stroke="red" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
</svg>

<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="20" class="non-scale">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" stroke="red" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
</svg>
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
<div style="width: 20px; height: 20px;"></div>
```

Comment: Нет CSS. Это чисто картинка

Comment: Тогда по второму варианту или добавить через тег <style>. Попробуйте, посмотрите.

Comment: @Leonid (+) Сейчас попробую объяснить немного по другому.